# Determine the month of a week based on in which month a certain weekday is?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want the user to enter year into A1.

I want the user to enter week number into A2.

I want the user to enter weekday (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday or Sunday) in A3.

Then I want A4 to calculate the month of the entered week number where weeks are counted as belonging to a certain month depending on if the specified weekday is in that month or not.

What formula would work in A4? (if you can not solve this problem, but can give me a formula that works if specified weekday can only be thursday, then I welcome that as well.

Comment: Have you tried anything, yet?

Comment: I have tried something like =CHOOSE(MONTH(DATE(YEAR;1;WEEK*7-N)-WEEKDAY(DATE(WEEK;1;3)));"Jan";"Feb";"Mar";"Apr";"Maj";"Jun";"Jul";"Aug";"Sep";"Okt";"Nov";"Dec") and varying N in that formula between 1 and 7, (Mon and Sun), but haven't gotten it to work. I don't exactly understand the formula.

Comment: My formula was inspired from here: http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1856-excel-get-month-from-week-number.html

Comment: do I unsterstand you correctly: you do want to use Excel not VBA?

Comment: Yes, you understand me correctly

Comment: How are you computing the weeknumber?  There are various methods used; the most common is the ISO standard (week 1 is the first week of the year containing a Thursday, and the first day of the week is  Monday), but there are others that your scheme might be using, and it will make a difference in the computation.

Comment: Is this also your question here? - http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/1041119-how-does-the-following-formula-set-the-month-based-on-week-number.html

Answer (score 0):

My idea would be something like that:

(weeknumber-1)*7 + Weekday -> Mon = 1, Tue = 2.... 
Check the Day of Year [0..365 or 366] and compare to an offset for Jan / Feb / March... depending on whether year has a 29th of Feb - which can be calculated using the year.

Now all you have to do is convert that to code.

EDIT:
After I read that page you reffered to, I assume you have trouble understanding Excels Date Syntax
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/date-function-HP010062283.aspx

So lets break that code down:
What happens here?

```
=CHOOSE(MONTH(DATE(A2,1,B2*7-2)-WEEKDAY(DATE(B2,1,3))),"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")
```

So lets pick that first DATE Statement:
Date (as stated in Microsoft's Doc) works as follows: If your month has more than 30/31 days the leftover days get dragged into the next month. So as A1 is the year (yyyy/mm/dd) B2 is the *day times 7* == the weeknumber minus some offset BECAUSE the first week shall not be counted (like it is week 1 day 3 but the formula would make it day 10 otherwise)

** https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/WEEKDAY-function-a9784177-5c31-4deb-bc9e-d4ab914983ca?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

** same with Month
https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/MONTH-function-EEDAC31A-E28C-46FB-B81F-CADB4BC03751?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

So what is it with the monthnames? 
Well, this is just a sinmple enumeration and the CHOOSE function in the very beginning will convert a number between 0...x into the value at the corresponding place in the enum, which is why the months have to be in order.

Comment: Maybe I didn't quire understand my problem. The thing is that when I use the function =MONTH(DATE(year;1;week*7-2)-WEEKDAY(DATE(week;1;3))) that I found online, it tells me that week 1 of 2014 is in December. But that is absurd. I want week 1 to be in January. How can I correct the formula?

Comment: This function uses ISO Week date numbers http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date. The definition is: Week 1 is the week with January 04 in it. So week 1 of 2014 starts in December 2013 with Monday 2013-12-30.

Comment: @user1283776 If you replace the -2 with +1, i.e. `=MONTH(DATE(year;1;week*7+1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(week;1;3)))` then that will take the Thursday of the week and calculate the month from that, which means that week 1 will always be in Jan and week 52/53 always in Dec (assuming your week numbers are ISO weeks).....but if you want the day to be flexible you need to have your week numbers defined so that week 1 is always wholly within Jan (which isn't the case with ISO weeks, as Axel says), so Ron's question (above) is relevant - how are week numbers defined for you?